# cannot find Big O notation library

Tags: java, big-o

Is there any library calculating big O notation, especially for Java language?

I've heard opinion that it is impossible to implement because of Halting problem. But this opinion was followed by explanaition of how to calculate it "by hand".

Is there any library automating that calculation?

Comment: How do you expect this library to work? You'd give it a piece of source code, and it'll tell you the asymptotic complexity?

Comment: Yes, or error if it cannot calculate that for the code.

Comment: It seems like the halting problem can be easily reduced to this problem. Any infinite complexity should return false (i.e. non-terminating), otherwise true. So theoretically speaking, this tool is impossible to implement. Perhaps there are partial solutions for limited scenarios.

Comment: Yes. That is what i'm looking for. "partial solutions for limited scenarios".

Comment: Actually there are tools that check the estimated complexity at *runtime*, by running the code multiple times with different input sizes, and calculating the asymptotic behavior. I saw this in http://codility.com/ for example.